# How are Coolors.co color schemes generated?

Tags: color, color-theory

Color schemes like Monochromatic, Analogous, Triadic, Tertiary are generated based off the color wheel. What about color schemes from Coolors.co or ColorSpace?

How would those schemes be generated? I'm asking because I would like to develop my own generator.